# Convert non standard text to date using Appscript

Tags: arrays, date, datetime, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

I know it's a very similar question at first, but I didn't find any question about converting an arbitrary non standard text to date format. This question is more about parsing a string then it's about converting to date format.

I have several Google sheets where the Column Date has many dates registered as a text in the style '16th day of February 2022', and not as a date. No Google sheet tool or any built-in method for java seems to be naturally capable of identify this arbitrary date format as a date.

In python, I could do something like

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
months={'january':01,'february':02,'etc:10'}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
   arbritary_date= row['Date'].split()
   for i in arbritary_date:
      if i in months:
          date= arbritary_date[0][:2]+'/'+str(months[i])+arbritary_date[4]
          #and then convert it to date using a built-in library.
```

But I'm trying to write this code using Appscript, so it would be much faster. Which is being very hard, because I'm still learning Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(IF(A1:A="", NA(), A1:A), 
 "(\d+).+?(of)(.+ \d{4})", "$1$3")*1)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

[image]

##### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXNQSZaulS0Gc838tS9O5IeERYACvAo-go9n_CGu5y8/copy)

Comment: Besides replacing all ',' with ';' , i did exactly the same, but this is the output :  Error
Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But ' 16 February 2022' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: @JhonBaptist can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Of course : https://file.io/HSxceL52XSd3 And thanks!

Comment: @JhonBaptist answer updated